# Creating a primary key in an extant sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, alter

SQL newbie here. I have a sqlite (3.23.1) database with a table, call it 'fp' with 109 columns and 494266 records. The table was not created with a primary key. I understand (as per http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) that I cannot create a primary key from the original table. Fine. I want to create a new table with an additional column, `'id'` that serves as the primary key, and then preserve the rest of `fp`'s schema and data.

I've used `.schema fp` to obtain the command originally used to create the table, and then just added in the necessary clause (is that the right terminology?):

`CREATE TABLE fp_new(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ... 109 more entries
)`

How can I populate this table efficiently? I would like to do something simple, but, appropriately, receive an error:

`sqlite> INSERT INTO fp_new SELECT * FROM fp;
Error: table fp_new has 110 columns but 109 values were supplied`

Is there a way to do this programatically without specifically naming the 109 columns I need to insert?

I tried to create a table with just an `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column and populating it with a range from 1 to 494266 using recursive triggers and then joining it against the original table on the implicit `row_id` column of the latter, but the recursion limit is 1000 and I would like to do this without having to recompile sqlite3, if possible.

I would believe that the answer is scattered throughout various stackexchange posts, but I can't seem to find just the right collection of what I need.

Thank you,
D

Comment: Do you realise that (unless you coded WITHOUT ROWID (*a special/different table without rowid column*)) that you do in fact have a primary key called **rowid** i.e. coding `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` just creates an alias for the **rowid** (unique 64bit signed integer). So you could refer to rowid in the existing table. Note this is just meant to be informational. I'd suggest defining an alias, they are perhaps easier to use. [You might find this interesting](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: @MikeT 'rowid' serves as a unique identifier only if it is aliased as you say, by coding 'column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'. If that is not the case, the 'rowid' of a given row can change upon insertion/deletion of rows and vacuuming. I forget the resource that mentions this. But short of declaring a column as 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY', 'rowid' doesn't function as a primary key.

Comment: **rowid** is always present and a unique integer identifer unless the table is defined using WITHOUT ROWID. as per **"In SQLite, table rows normally have a 64-bit signed integer ROWID which is unique among all rows in the same table. (WITHOUT ROWID tables are **the** exception.)".** The fact that rowid's may be changed by a vacuum does not negate it generally being the most efficient and thus very often the selected index for query planning. What Vacuuming does potentially negate/hinder is it's use as other than it's use as a unique row identifier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a query that supplies 110 columns.

This is not a problem, because `*` does not need to be the only thing:

```
INSERT INTO fp_new SELECT NULL, * FROM fp;
```

Comment: This incurs    
    
sqlite> INSERT INTO flights SELECT NULL, * from flight_performance;
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: flights.INTEGER

Comment: You did not mention any UNIQUE constraint (that the original table does not have).

Comment: The original table doesn't have any such constraint. But doesn't creating the new table with 'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY' introduce a unique constraint?

Comment: The NULL ends up as [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). [This example works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/50082/1).